# QT signal and slot connection not working

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a simple game and want to send a signal from my Game class to my MainWindow. My signal and slot share the same parameter but I can't connect them. I have tried sending very simple signals with a dummy variable but failed to connect. The code is as follows.

game.h

```
class Game : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Game();
signals:
    void test(int l);
```

MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void testSlot(int l);
```

game.cpp

```
void someFunction(){
    emit test(2);
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
      g{new Game()}

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    g->gameLoop();
    connect(g,&Game::test,this,&MainWindow::testSlot);

}
```

How can I get the signals and slots to connect properly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes you think the connect isn't working?

Comment: I have put a qDebug() statement which prints the variable I am sending to test it. It doesn't get printed. The sender and the receiver however are correctly displayed when I look at them in the debugger.

Comment: `g->gameLoop()` I hope that gameLoop() ends and is not a `while (true)` type loop. Remember that if your function does not end Qt will not update the GUI.

Comment: Don't worry, it isn't an infinite loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be in the fact that you have `g->gameLoop();` BEFORE the `connect`. If your `someFunction` is called from the `gameLoop`, then the `connect` is performed only after the game has finished and after the execution returns from the `gameLoop()`. But of course it's just guessing. I wouldn't expect to see 'gameLoop' called from the Window's constructor so.. it looks odd as well. Other than that, it looks fine, so if my guess is not correct, then probably the problem lies elsewhere in the code we don't see.

Comment: Exactly as you said, the emit happens in the gameloop() function.

Comment: Thank you for this response. Moving the code inside the  gameLoop() from the MainWindow's constructor to the Game's constructor solved the issue.